# How to get rid of Highcharts warning

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this really annoying warning in the webconsole when running my app.

```
Highcharts warning: Consider including the "accessibility.js" module to make your chart more usable for people with disabilities. Set the "accessibility.enabled" option to false to remove this warning. See https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module.
```

I'm running the chartkick gem, importing it like this:

```
import "chartkick/highcharts";
```

I can't seem to figure out how to rid myself of this warning. Read Highchart and Chartkick documentation, but alas!

Comment: Did you actually read the error ?- because it specifically tells you how to remove it.

Comment: @YestheCia I did and I tried adding this to the view that has the chart. 

```
<script>

    Highcharts.chart('container',
      {
        accessibility: {
          enabled: false,

        } })

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the accessibility option in Highcharts to false.

Using Chartkick, you normally have to use that to pass the options to the underlying charting library.

You will need to do something like:

```
# You can pass options directly to the charting library with:

<%= line_chart data, library: {accessibility: {enabled: false}} %>
```

Or after load, but this would suppress the warning on the page load.

```
var chart = Chartkick.charts["chart-id"]

const newOptions = {accessibility: {enabled: false}
chart.setOptions(newOptions)
```

I haven't tested either of these as we use Chart.js but this is how we pass params to the charting library.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not have enouch reputation to upvote! But your answer was correct!!